# passing a value returning function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I'm tasked with passing a value returning function named circle that returns
the values for area and circumference. I always get an 'area not defined' error.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
import math
PI = math.pi

def main():
     rad = float(input("Enter radius: "))
     circle(rad)
     area, circ = circle(rad)
     print ("Circle area is " + format(area, ',.3f'))
     print ("Circle circumference is " + format(circ, ',.3f'))
def circle(rad):
     area = rad ** 2 * PI
     circ = 2 * rad * PI
     return area,circ
main()
```

I can't get it to acknowledge area/circ as defined.

Comment: Hmmm. You're right. But it wouldn't run when I tried it at home. I must have goofed somewhere. I appreciate you confirming that for me. I'm new to programming and have a ways to go. Thanks!

Comment: No problems. Besides, you can replace first 2 lines with `from math import pi as PI`

Comment: usually it means problem is with whitespaces/indent somewhere, it's a Python after all...